# „Wie lange brauchen Sie?“, „Wie lange dauert?“ und „Bis wann?“

Tags: word-choice, usage, time

> Q. Wie lange brauchen Sie für die Reparatur?
>
> A. Zwei Stunden.

Aber kann man auch „bis morgen“ oder „bis in zwei Stunden“ sagen?

> Q.Wie lange dauert die Reparatur?
>
> A. Etwa drei Tage.

Aber kann man auch „bis morgen“ oder „bis in drei Tagen“ sagen?

> Q. Bis wann können Sie das reparieren?
>
> A. Bis in zwei Stunden.

Ist die Antwort möglich? Oder sollte man exakte Zeit wie „bis morgen“ oder „bis elf Uhr“ sagen?

Comment: I corrected a spelling mistake: The plural of _Stunde_ is _Stunde**n**_. Thus, correct is _(bis in) zwei Stunde**n**_.

Answer (score 2):

Mit "Wie lange brauchen Sie für die Reparatur?" und "Wie lange dauert die Reparatur?" fragt man nach einer Zeitdauer. Da sind die Antworten "Zwei Stunden" und "Etwa drei Tage" jeweils korrekt und austauschbar. Jede Zeit-Einheit (eine Stunde, ein Tag, usw.) ist als relative Zeitangabe eine korrekte Antwort. Start- und End-Zeitpunkt sind hier nicht definiert. Damit der Fragende weiß, zu welchem absoluten Zeitpunkt der jenige fertig ist, muss er auch noch wissen, wann die Reparaturarbeit begonnen wurde.

Mit "Bis wann können Sie das reparieren?" fragt man nach einem absoluten Zeitpunkt. Die Antwort "Bis in zwei Stunden" ist richtig: Sie beschreibt den Zeitpunkt, der in zwei Stunden gegenwärtig ist. Der Fragende will hier nicht wissen, wann die Reparatur begonnen wurde oder wie lange sie dauert, sondern nur, wann sie fertig ist. Merke: Antworten auf "Bis wann ..." können immer auf einen genauen Tag und Uhrzeit bestimmt werden (ohne Startzeitpunkt der Reparatur, Dauer etc. zu wissen). (Abgesehen natürlich von Variablen-Benutzung wie z. B. "Ich bin dann fertig, wenn das Ereignis XY eingetreten ist", aber das ist ein anderes Thema.)

"Wie lange brauchen Sie?" - "Bis in zwei Stunden." klingt nicht schlecht, versteht auch jeder, ist aber genau genommen nicht richtig, da es eine Antwort auf die "Wann sind sie fertig?"-Frage ist.
Es muss hingegen bei der Frage nach einem Zeitpunkt die Antwort eindeutig auf einen Zeitpunkt referenzieren, egal zu welchem Zeitpunkt gefragt wird. Beispiel: "Bis wann sind sie fertig?" "Bis in 2 Stunden" -> Die Antwort meint den Zeitpunkt in 2 Stunden, das könnte z. B. der 12.12.2016 12:10 sein. Wenn man später fragt, wann die Reparatur fertig wurde, muss die Antwort auf den Zeitpunkt 12.12.2016 12:10 referenzieren, auch wenn die Formulierung dann abhängig vom Antwortzeitpunkt z. B. "Vor 4 Tagen und 6 Stunden" ist.

Comment: "da man auf den selben Zeitpunkt referenziert" - da man dieselbe *Zeitdauer* angibt, oder? Wenn es um einen Zeitpunkt geht, muss auch andernorts die Antwort angepasst werden: "Bis wann können Sie das reparieren?" - "Bis in zwei Stunden." (drei Stunden später) "Bis wann haben Sie daran gearbeitet?" - "Bis vor einer Stunde."

Comment: danke für den hinweis, ich hab das nochmal umformuliert//korrigiert

Comment: Ich finde: "Wie lange brauchen Sie?" - "Bis in zwei Stunden." klingt schlecht!

Answer (score -2):

In allen drei Fällen sind jeweils alle drei Antwortmöglichkeiten erlaubt und hören sich auch nicht sonderbar oder komisch an.

Bemerkung: bei der ersten Frage sollten es Stunde*n* sein. Bei der Zweiten sind die in der Frage gegebenen "etwa zwei Tage" (ohne n), aber "bis in drei Tage*n*" richtig.

Comment: I corrected the spelling mistake _Stunde**n**_ in the question. I think, it was just a slip of the pen, because in the end of the question it was qritten correctly.

Comment: I disargree with this answer. I think, it sound strange to answer "Q.Wie lange dauert die Reparatur?" or "Q. Wie lange brauchen Sie für die Reparatur? " with "Bis in drei Tagen" ("Bis morgen" on the other hand is fine)

Comment: Kleinere Fehler, wie in diesem Fall das Schluss-*n,* sollten Gegenstand eines Edits (und gegebenenfalls eines klärenden Kommentars sein; das kann aber auch die Editbegründung liefern) und nicht Bestandteil der Antwort sein – vor Allem, wenn sie den Kernpunkt der Frage nicht betreffen.